# How to use geometry_msgs/Twist.h?

Tags: ros, compile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to use stage with ROS. So I have modified the talker.cpp code, from the tutorial, to control the robot of the stage's tutorial. I have changed the declaration of the publisher to this:

```
 ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1000);
```

And I add this too:

```
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
```

My problem is that the code cant compile because this library cant be found.
The error given by the compiler is :

```
ros_workspace/stage_controllers/src/talker.cpp:4:33: error fatal: geometry_msgs/Twist.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio compilación terminada.
```

Its in spanish, but it means: fatal error: geometry_msgs/Twist.h: The file or directory doesn't exist, compilation finished.

I have tried to add the route of this file to the $PATH (/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/geometry_msgs/msg_gen/cpp/include/geometry_msgs/Twist.h) and have done all the ros.org tutorial.
So where should I add this route to makes it compile?
Thanks for your time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30952/how-to-use-geometry_msgs/twist.h-?/) by [CoderKai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2099/coderkai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-04-01**:
Please always copy-paste the error messages you get. It's hard to guess what's going wrong. http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have a dependency on geometry_msgs in you manifest, geometry_msgs needs to be in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and geometry_msgs needs to have been built.  If you rosmake with it in you dependencies this will be done for you.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2